# How entity framework works when providerName configuration is missing?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is my configuration from one of my console applications which is using entity framework:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  ....omitted few things for brevity
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
  <add  name="codefirst" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SomeCatalog;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

So here the connection string has an attribute `providerName`. I mention it as `System.Data.SqlClient` because I've already defined one provider inside `entityFramework` section with this name. This is ok.

But in the below configuration which is full content of `App.Config` file of my another console application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EfTestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EFTest.csdl|res://*/EFTest.ssdl|res://*/EFTest.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=EfTest;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I mention the `providerName` as `System.Data.EntityClient`. But here I don't have any `entityFramework` section where I've give a provider with name `System.Data.EntityClient`. Still my application works. My application is able to connect to the database in the connection string and do what is directed through entity framework context.

Why the later connection string just works for EF even though `Providers` information is missing from the application configuration file? Is it missing or it is located somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first connection string is for code-first approach. That one does not specify `.csdl`, `.ssdl` and `.msl` files. EF will generate those files from your code-first model though. In this connection string you need to specify `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`.

In the 2nd application you have, the connection string is for database first approach. That one, as you can see, specifies `.csdl`, `.ssdl` and `.msl` files. It also has this in the connection string: `provider=System.Data.SqlClient` and `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`. Therefore, it knows to use `EntityClient` as the data provider for EF, and `SqlClient` as the data provider for SQL Server.

Therefore, it is all there. But they are different for code-first and database first.

Comment: Where are these meta data files namely `EFTest.csdl`, `EFTest.msl` and `EFTest.ssdl` located? I've searched my entire solution explorer but I don't see them any where.

Comment: Select your project in solution explorer > Show All Files > Obj >

Comment: @RBT were you able to find them?

Comment: Yes. I can see them.

Comment: But the problem still remains. How the program is able to figure out `System.Data.EntityClient` as a database provider even when it is missing from the providers list in my `app.config` file. In fact, I don't have any providers section at all my `app.config` file. Those *.csdl, *.ssdl and *.msl files contain meta information related to the schema of database tables. They don't tell anything about the provider?

Comment: 2nd one has provider=System.Data.SqlClient and providerName="System.Data.EntityClient". What else would it need?

Comment: That first one has that too but it has to `providers` section too at the top of the config file to tell the application as to what does `System.Data.SqlClient` provider name means. Second one has no `providers` section at the top of the configuration file but still it is able to figure out the meaning of `System.Data.EntityClient` provider. How?

Comment: No the 2nd one has `System.Data.EntityClient` and that figures out what the provider is from `provider=System.Data.SqlClient` in its connection string.

Comment: Ohh! Now I got it. My bad. I missed the `provider` fragment inside the `connectionString`itself in the second code snippet. In fact, I reread your post now after all these discussions and it makes complete sense. I'm able to connect all the dots now. Sorry for being a nagging asker.

Comment: Do you think I should reword it to make it more clear? If yes, please suggest how?